# Magento Custom Module database query

Tags: magento

I have written a module to add my own events, and in the home page i would like to show only latest events. So in that case i have to add order by to query but i couldnot do that, it always throws fatal error.

This is what i have done.

```
$_offers = Mage::getSingleton('offerings/offerings')->getCollection();
```

This returns all the records, here i could able to set filter options but i could not add sort order like this

```
$_offers = Mage::getModel('offerings/offerings')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSort('offerings_id', 'DESC')
            ->setPageSize(5)
            ->setPage(1, 5);
```

or even using  Mage::getSingleton. Whats the problem here am facing. Please help me

Comment: What class does your offerings collection extend? Is it EAV based? Also, what is the fatal error thrown?

Comment: it doesnot extend EAV Class and so i could nto use the sort filter method. it throws Fatal Error : addAttributeToSort method couldnot find...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't put in the time to test but I suspect you need to do something like this:

```
$_offers = Mage::getModel('offerings/offerings')->getCollection()
            ->setOrder('offerings_id', 'DESC')
            ->setPageSize(5);
```

As pointed out the EAV method `addAttributeToSort()` won't work here.  Nor will `setPage()` but `setPageSize()` is just as good.

There are plenty of tutorials and guides around to learn this stuff from. Alan's [knowledgebase articles](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections) are the authoritative resource on the subject, you would do well to read and practice it all.

Answer (score 0):

Include an error message and people can start helping you.

My guess if you've used Module Creator to create your module, which gives you a default non-eav model and collection.  The addAttributeToSort method only exists for EAV collections.

There's more information on your various sorting options here

[Magento get a product collection in an arbitrary order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990266/magento-get-a-product-collection-in-an-arbitrary-order/3990800#3990800)

Comment: exactly, you are right. Used Module creator and it doesnot extend the EAV classes, so how could i use the query to sort it out. thanks