# Magento Sort By The Percentage Discount

Tags: php, magento

I have a custom page that I have put together that basically shows products that are on sale. I was asked if I could sort the products coming out of the collection by the highest percentage of discount.

So I am wondering if it is possible to set the order of products based on the mathematical result of diving two other attributes together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Alan Storm previously helped me with a similar problem I was having sorting products in an arbitrary way.

[Magento get a product collection in an arbitrary order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990266/magento-get-a-product-collection-in-an-arbitrary-order)

Using the same idea I came up with the following code to make this work:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('price')
->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('neq' => ""))
->addAttributeToFilter('discontinued', array('neq' => 1))
->setPageSize($results_per_page)
->setCurPage($current_page)
;

$products->getSelect()->order('(`e`.special_price / `e`.`price`)', 'DESC');
```

Credit should go to Alan Storm on this one.

Comment: what does it mean e.special_price or e.price

Comment: If you did an echo "$products->getSelect()" you would see the query that is being run. The primary table you are selecting from is called e in the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Smart Sorting Extension for Magento](http://add-in-mage.com/magento-extensions/smart-sorting-extension.html).

It lets your customers [sort products](http://add-in-mage.com/magento-extensions/smart-sorting-extension.html) in your store’s catalogue in 9 new ways:

**Now in Wishlists** (real time),

**Now in Carts** (real time),

**Biggest $ Saving**,

**Biggest % Saving**,

**Customers’ Choice**,

**Most Discussed**,

**Most Appreciated**,

**Most Recent**,

**Most Viewed**.

Answer (score 0):

use:
$products->getSelect()
         ->order('1 - (**price_index.final_price** / e.price)', 'DESC');

so even if you have some rules promotions active there are considered.

Answer (score 0):

D. Militos answer was correct for me, with a slight correction:

$products->getSelect() ->order('1 - (price_index.final_price / **price_index**.price)', 'DESC');